# What profit of using multi-threaded coroutines?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I work with coroutines pretty long time, but I still don't understand completely, why do I need to prefer multi-threaded coroutines instead of single-threaded coroutines.

I can clearly see the profit of using multi-threaded coroutines when their count is less or equal to the physical thread count. But if we have more tasks than physical threads, why wouldn't we rather use only one coroutine thread?

I'll clarify the final question: **Why is 10 threads of coroutines better than only one thread with many coroutines?**

Comment: I have to admiit I can't follow your train of thought. First, if you have less tasks than physical cores, you don't even need coroutines, native threads will do just fine. Second, the thinking that it takes _less_ threads when you have _more_ coroutines, completely escapes all my earnest attempts to understand your angle.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I was also pretty confused, but I got an impression that OP assumes coroutines are somehow scheduled directly on CPU cores. So if there are enough coroutines to occupy all cores, there is no need for threads. And if there are less coroutines than cores then MT could somehow... err, I don't know, make coroutines run faster by utilizing free cores? Of course, that doesn't make any sense at all. Coroutines are not scheduled on CPU cores, but on threads. Then threads are scheduled on CPU cores.

Comment: I know that coroutines settles in threads, I just thought that some coroutines can work simultaneously in one thread and don't understand why do I need more threads than one. Now It seems I understand how it works, Joffrey gave me a good answer.

Comment: I guess your confusion stems from the way the word "concurrent" is used, and that it's a different technical term from "parallel". You can have many _concurrent_ coroutines on one thread, but they will not run in _parallel_. Parallel execution is only possible on separate CPU cores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coroutines are units of computation (like tasks). The way they are dispatched onto actual threads is orthogonal to how many coroutines you have. You can use a single-threaded dispatcher or a multi-threaded dispatcher, and depending on this your coroutines will be scheduled differently.

Multi-threaded coroutines doesn't mean 1 thread per coroutine. You can dispatch 100 coroutines on 8 threads.

> But if we have more tasks than physical threads, why wouldn't we rather use only one coroutine thread?

There are multiple parts in this question.

First, if you have more tasks than logical cores, you could still dispatch all those tasks onto just the right number of threads. You don't have to completely give up on multithreading. This is actually exactly what `Dispatchers.Default` is about: dispatching as many coroutines as you want onto a limited number of threads equal to the number of hardware threads (logical cores) that you have. The point is to make use of all the hardware as much as possible without wasting theads (and thus memory).

Second, not every task is CPU-bound. Some I/O operations block threads (network calls, disk reads/writes etc.). When a thread is blocked on I/O, it doesn't use the CPU. If you have 8 logical cores, using only 8 threads for I/O would be suboptimal, because while some threads are blocked, the CPU cannot run other tasks. With more threads, it can (at the cost of some memory). This is the point of `Dispatchers.IO`, which can create more threads as needed and can exceed the number of logical cores (within a reasonable limit).

> Why is 10 threads of coroutines better than only one thread with many coroutines?

Let's assume you have 100 coroutines to dispatch.

Using only one thread to run those coroutines implies that only 1 core at most is doing the work at a given time, so nothing happens in parallel. This means all the other cores are idle, which is suboptimal. Worse, any I/O operation done by a coroutine blocks this only thread and prevents the CPU from doing anything while we're waiting on I/O.

Using 10 threads, you can literally execute 10 coroutines at the same time if your hardware is sufficient, which can be 10x faster (if your coroutines don't have inter-dependencies).

Using 100 threads would not be that beneficial if your coroutines are CPU-bound, but might be useful if you have a bunch of I/O tasks (as we've seen). That said, the more threads you use, the more memory is consumed. So even with a ton of I/O operations, you have to find a balance between throughput and memory, you don't want to spawn millions of threads.

In short, using multi-threading still has the same advantages with or without coroutines: it allows to make use of your hardware resources as much as possible. Using coroutines is just an easier way to define tasks, dispatch them onto threads, express dependencies, avoid blocking threads unnecessarily, etc.